# How can I prevent a program from mapping files?

Tags: memory, file-management, windows-11

I have some programs which use big files (writing to them mainly) and whenever they're running my computer almost runs out of memory because those big files are in memory (shown by Sysinternals RAMmap).

Is there any way of making these concrete programs unable to map files into memory without forcing the entire system not to map anything? There are some programs I want to still be able to map stuff, by the way.

Comment: For Apps, do not start them if you do not want them in memory. Services and base apps should not take more than about 4 GB total.  Please be specific about what Apps are an issue for you,

Answer (score 0):

> my computer almost runs out of memory

*Almost* is not *has*.  Your computer will use as much memory as it has available.  If those programs are open and writing to those file, then those files will be in memory.  You can continue working on your computer with no issues.  If you open enough applications that are actively using memory and that exceeds the amount of RAM you have, then it will start swapping memory to disk. Swapping will slow down your computer, but until that happens, there is no issue.

Comment: The thing is, it will run out of memory when I play a open world game, for example, and swapping won't be fast enough to assure a good gaming experience. Either my game crashes because it reads faster than my memory can handle or it will lag way too much for my liking.

Comment: @NéstorLlop Then you have 2 choices:  1) Get more memory or 2) dont run the game and the programs at the same time.